# Comparing a value with previous row in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, comparison

In a `while()` statement, is there a way to know if a value in a row is equal to a value in the previous row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$get = mysql_query("...");
$previous = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
  $current = $row['...'];
  if ($current == $previous) {
  // do stuff
}
$previous = $current;
}
```

This example won't work correctly.  It will always skip the first record in the array.
The first time through $previous will be blank so $current and $previous won't be equal. 
$current will have to blank the first pass, just as previous.
$current will have to be made equal inside the if loop.

```
$get = mysql_query("...");
$previous = '';
$current = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {

  if ($current == $previous) {
     $current = $row['...'];
    // do stuff
   }
 $previous = $current;
}
```

Comment: good call, I also wondered why it kept skipping the first row.

Answer (score 20):

Just store it:

```
$get = mysql_query("...");
$previous = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
  $current = $row['...'];
  if ($current == $previous) {
    // do stuff
  }
  $previous = $current;
}
```