# Subtract previous variable from current variable (or itself if first iteration) while looping

Tags: php, loops, variables, while-loop, subtraction

I need to subtract the value from the previous iteration from the current iteration's value. On the first iteration, there will be no previous value, so the result should be zero.

For example (expected value)

[image: expected output]

and my code was as below:

```
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT RIGHT(serial,4) as value, serial, date 
    from photodata 
    where folder='$m' or (serial >= '$cm' && serial <= '$cm2')") or die(mysql_error());

while ($selt=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $value = $selt['value'];
    $ser = $selt['serial'];
    $dd = $selt['date'];
    $rr = $value-$value;  
}
```

I'm really sure `$rr` won't work, but I just tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a value with previous row in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739807/comparing-a-value-with-previous-row-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: @BilalAhmed thats maybe look same but what I need is for my situation, my variable. Their solution didn't works here

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print $rr as subtract value and check, changed some code in above snippet. Hope, it will help you out.

```
$index = 0;
$oldv = 0;
while ($selt=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $value = $selt['value'];
    $ser = $selt['serial'];
    $dd = $selt['date']; 
    if($index==0) {
        $oldv = $value;
        $index = 1;
     }
    $rr = $value - $oldv;
    echo $rr;
    $oldv = $value;
 }
```

Comment: You do not need to print $oldv.... Your original value is in $value variable and the Subtract value is in $rr variable.

Comment: can you provide some more explanation about your snippet? also make sure to read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to subtract the value of previous row. Though it is recommended you don't use mysql_* functions.

```
$oldv = 0;
while ($selt=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
 $oldv = ($oldv == 0) ? $value : $oldv;
 $value= $selt['value'];
 $ser=$selt['serial'];
 $dd=$selt['date'];
 echo $subtract = $value - $oldv;
 echo $oldv = $value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand this, because when I echo $oldv, it just show me the exact value of $value.

Comment: well this is just a snippet. After the end of the while loop $oldv would be the last value in the table. You might need to take the data into an array.

Comment: @I'mAGurl I added an if condition to get the first subtracted result to be 0.

Comment: I'm so sorry, can you give me the example of array? Because when I tried to run this edited code, still the same I get the same $value value by row. But what I need is the subtraction value between row1 and row2(for example) I've uploaded the image for your review

Answer (score 0):

- A while loop is not the modern way to loop the rows; just pass the result set object directly to a `foreach()` loop and treat each row like an associative array.
- While iterating, subtract the previous value from the current value. If there is no previous value, subtract the current value from itself to get the `0` asked for in the question.
- After subtracting, overwrite the cached previous value variable with the current value, then continue looping.

Here is a basic demo: https://3v4l.org/pJpDT

```
$sel = <<<SQL
SELECT RIGHT(serial,4) as value,
       serial,
       date 
FROM photodata 
WHERE folder=?
    OR serial BETWEEN ? AND ?
SQL;

$rows = $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$m, $cm, $cm2]);
$result = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $result[] = $row + [
        'sub' => $row['value'] - ($prev ?? $row['value'])
    ];
    $prev = $row['value'];
}
var_export($result);
```